# SMTP Send is locking up my files - c#

Tags: c#, smtp, locked-files

I have a function thats sending messages ( a lot of them) and their attachments.

It basically loops through a directory structure and creates emails from a file structure for example

```
 c:\emails\message01
                \attachments
 c:\emails\message02
                \attachments
```

The creation of the messages takes place using .net c#, standard stuff.

After all messages are created... I have another function that runs directly afterwards that copies the message folder to another location.

Problem is - files are locked...

Note: I'm not moving the files, just copying them....

Any suggestions on how to copy locked files, using c#?

**Update**

I have this add attachments method

```
    private void AddAttachments(MailMessage mail)
    {
        string attachmentDirectoryPath = "c:\messages\message1";
        DirectoryInfo attachmentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(attachmentDirectoryPath);
        FileInfo[] attachments = attachmentDirectory.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo attachment in attachments)
        {
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment.FullName));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

How are you reading the files to create the email message? They should be opened as read-only, with a `FileShare` set to `FileShare.ReadWrite`... then they shouldn't be locked. If you are using a `FileStream` you should also wrap your logic in the `using` keyword so that the resource is disposed properly.

#### Update:

I believe disposing the mail message itself will close resources within it and unlock the files:

```
using (var mail = new MailMessage())
{
    AddAttachments(mail);
}
// File copy code should work here
```

Comment: Is there anything that I could do to the code above, to make it dispose property, I really thought the garbage collector would take care of it, maybe I am wrong?

Comment: Thanks John - I believe your answer of disposing the mail object itself is best case scenario, as pointed out by Luke

Comment: I too love you for this, spent all afternoon looking for this solution!

Comment: Thanks you so much for saving my life

Comment: You are awesome. This is the perfect solution

Answer (score 22):

hate answering my own post, but yeah for the next poor guy who has this problem here is the fix:

**AFTER YOU SEND THE MESSAGE**

```
        // Send the mail
        client.Send(message);

        //Clean up attachments
        foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
        {
            attachment.Dispose();
        }
```

Dispose the attachments... clears the lock, and messages will still be sent with attachments. Dispose DOES NOT delete the files, just clears the attachments :)

Comment: John Rasch has the correct answer: You should dispose of the `MailMessage` itself (preferably by wrapping it in a `using` block). The `Dispose` method of the `MailMessage` also disposes any attachments.

Answer (score 3):

Are you closing the files after you finish reading them? If you open them for reading, but don't close them when you're done, it should keep a lock on it until the program exits and automatically closes all the files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - not really opening the files, just adding them, like in the code above

Answer (score 2):

```
    MailMessage email = new MailMessage();

    email.From = txtFrom.Text;
    email.To = txtToEmail.Text;
    email.Subject = txtMSubject.Text; 
    email.Body = txtBody.Text;

    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();
    mailClient.Host = "smtp.emailAddress";
    mailClient.Port = 2525;
    mailClient.Send(email );
    email.Dispose();

    // After Disposing the email object you can call file delete

    if (filePath != "")
    {
      if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
      {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath); 
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should work with ASync sending also if you pass the MailMessage object to it in the user parameters

Answer (score 0):

I see this a lot when sending attachments.  I normally use something like the following:

In the code that moves the files to a different location, you can use the following pattern:

Inside the loop for looping through the files

```
bool FileOk = false;
while (!FileOk)
{
   try
   {
      // code to move the file
      FileOk = true;
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
      // do nothing or write some code to pause the thread for a few seconds.
   }

}
```

Comment: Don't really want to go this route, for the reason that another process like indexing service could lock the file, creating a dead link in my app, but thanks for the suggestion.