# the process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process. and Access to the path 'filename' is denied

Tags: c#, ioexception

I am trying to find the size of file and store the size in `string fileSize = string.Empty;`.
for this i am saving the file with unique name and then reading finally deleting the file .

I am sometime getting error either in reading or deleting the file.

while reading i am getting this error

> the process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)

while deleting i am getting this error

> Access to the path 'filename' is denied.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)

my code is:

```
bool checksize(Outlook.Attachment attachment)
{
string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmssff");
if (!Directory.Exists(GetConfigSettings("folderPath")))
{
Directory.CreateDirectory(GetConfigSettings("folderPath"));
}
attachment.SaveAsFile(GetConfigSettings("folderPath") + "\\"+ currentTime + "_" + attachment.FileName);


using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(GetConfigSettings("folderPath") + "\\"+ currentTime + "_" + attachment.FileName), FileMode.Open)))
{
fileSize = br.BaseStream.Length.ToString();
}

File.Delete(GetConfigSettings("folderPath") + "\\"+ currentTime + "_" + attachment.FileName));
//somecode
}
```

I am not getting why randomly it throws exception.

Comment: Probably because [File locked after sending it as attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191449/file-locked-after-sending-it-as-attachment)

Comment: you don't need a binaryReader, just use the stream that is returned by File.Open(...)

Comment: Either your disposable objects (stream and reader) are not disposed quick enough or Outlook.Attachment.SaveAsFile(...) does not dispose correctly

Comment: The attachment object has a method `Size` - can you use that instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.size

Comment: @D.J. how to dispose  stream and reader object, stream and reader are under using statement so they should dispose automatically.  also `attachment.Dispose();` is not valid command as it is showing red line below Dispose.

Comment: @mohdsarfaraz reader is in using-statment, the stream is not. also you do not need reader AND stream for your purpose. i didn't suggest 'attachment.Dispose()'. i meant that the method or class does not propery dispose stuff in its inner workings

Comment: @D.J. i am not getting how to resolve this issue, can you please provide me the code or give idea how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps your create-open-delete is being held back by a virus scanner or something.

Comment: issue which i figured it out is that when saving big file it takes some time and i that particular time i am trying to read that file , that is why exception `the process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process.` is thrown.
now how to give time to save file and then only read the file ,
similar situation for delete also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding wait in between save and read solved my issue.

```
attachment.SaveAsFile(GetConfigSettings("folderPath") + "\\"+ currentTime + "_" + attachment.FileName);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(GetConfigSettings("folderPath") + "\\"+ currentTime + "_" + attachment.FileName), FileMode.Open)))
{
fileSize = br.BaseStream.Length.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of saving the attachment to a temporary file, opening this file using an irrelevant reader and then checking the reader's base stream's length, only to then delete the file again, use `Outlook.Attachment.Size`.

You can replace your entire method with this:

```
bool checksize(Outlook.Attachment attachment)
{
    filesize = attachment.Size.ToString();
    return true;
}
```

Also, the signature `bool checksize` doesn't really make sense, nor does storing the filesize in a class member, nor does storing it as a string, but that's not what your question was about.

Comment: actually i tried with `attachment.Size.ToString()` but it does not give exact size, for empty file it does not give 0 size.